# how to set headers in php for safety

Tags: php

I'm being told to find the unsafe in this code and find a way to fix it.
Someone can help me ?

```
<?php
    $file_url = 'upload/news'.$_GET['file'];
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"". basename($file_url)."\"");
    readfile($file_url);
?>
```

Comment: you are open to path traversal in the `$file_url` value, is the `$_GET['file']` always a filename? If so you could use `basename($_GET['file'])` to only get the filename

Comment: if i use the above method is there any unsafe point ? I need to find the unsafe point of the code

Comment: Does the code actually use `$GET` instead of `$_GET`? Or is that a typo when you copied this code to StackOverflow?

Comment: rickdenhaan, thanks i edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_GET['file']` usage in the `$file_url` exposes the code to path traversal attacks. This is quite a dangerous setup, any file in the `news` directory can be read, if you place sensitive files like `.env` in the `news` folder they can be read!

If all content should be public you can use `pathinfo` to ensure you only get filenames. Checkout the following example:

```php
$fileName = basename($GET['file']);
$fileUrl = 'upload/news/'. $fileName

header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $fileName."\"");
readfile($fileUrl);
```

`basename` is safe to use in this case because it removes any path part that could be used for path traversal

```php
basename("../test.php"); // test.php
basename("."); // .
basename("../.."); // ..
basename("../../test.php"); // test.php
```